# How to pass an aws IAM role to a Java client (through a lambda function)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm aiming to create a lambda function which it will execute a java client, such (the java client) is supposed to call an aws service endpoint.

Since my java client needs authentication (I am approaching this with the AWS4Signer library). I would like to authenticate my java code with the IMDS of my lambda exception role, as **I can't use users due to a sec procedures**.

I've been trying to use *InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider* as my credential provider
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html
which in theory it should take the IMDS of the instance.Not sure if it only when using an EC2 instance, or it could also work with any aws compute service, such as lambda is.

with *InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider* I'm getting the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher - Token is not supported. Ignoring
Failed to connect to service endpoint: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:
at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
```

I came across with the following blogs where a similar issue was resported

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2285
- https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/service-slow-to-retrieve-aws-credentials-ebc02a38e95b

and it seems this is happening due to the catched instance credentials is already outdated at the time to authenticate the credentials.

So I have added a logic to refresh the credentialsProvider object (InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider)

````
 public static Optional<AWSCredentials> retrieveCredentials (AWSCredentialsProvider provider){

        var attempts = 0;
        System.out.println("Retrieving credentials...");
        try {
            System.out.printf("Retrieving credentials at attempt : %s", attempts);
            return Optional.of(provider.getCredentials());
        }catch(Exception e){
            while(attempts < 15) {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.printf("Retrieving credentials at attempt : %s", attempts);
                provider.refresh();
                    try {
                        return Optional.of(provider.getCredentials());
                    }catch (Exception e1){
                        System.out.printf("Attempt : %s failed due to: %s", attempts, e1.getMessage());
                    }
                attempts ++;
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);

        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
    ``` 


But I'm still getting the same error.



Any kind of help will be very appreciated.
````

Comment: What do you mean by "a lambda function which it will execute a java client"? Are you simply saying that the AWS Lambda function is written in Java? Or is the Lambda function calling something else? Please provide more information.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein what I meant for the java client, is a java application which will communicate with another aws service through a REST API call. The lambda function (written in terraform) will be only to compute the java application.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. While an AWS Lambda function can be _deployed_ via Terraform, it needs to be written in a language (eg Java, Python, C#). Will the Lambda function be this "Java client" you are mentioning? Normally, an IAM Role is assigned to an AWS Lambda function, which provides AWS credentials to the Lambda function. This allows the Lambda function to call other AWS services. Is this what you are seeking?